# Spring thymeleaf security sec:authentication not working

Tags: spring, spring-security, configuration, thymeleaf

I've searched a lot for this specific problem and currently no methods solving it worked for my project. I'm using spring-boot-starter security v.2.7.0 and thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5. The problem is I want to display the name of the user on a web page like this:

```html
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
        Welcome <span sec:authentication="name">Username</span>
    </div>
```

The th:sec is this:

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
```

I tried to display the name of the user in my controller and it works as expected:

```
@GetMapping("")
public String showHomePage(){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("username: " + auth.getName());

    return "index";
}
```

So for example the user with name "admin" logs in:

```
username: admin
```

But on the web page it displays "Welcome Username". The only guess I have is that the link

```
xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"
```

is 404. Is this the problem? If so, what is the valid link?

UPD: this is the dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.historicalReferenceBook</groupId>
<artifactId>historicalReferenceBook</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>historicalReferenceBook</name>
<description>historicalReferenceBook</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-money</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: It is a namespace not a link. You are also using Spring Boot 3 which isn't final and for which support of Thymeleaf isn't added yet. Even worse you are mixing Spring Boot versions. Fix the mixing (use 2.7 for the parent), remove the `version` tag from `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` and `spring-boot-security-starter`. remove the `validation-api` dependency and add `spring-boot-starter-validation`. Remove the `sec` namespace from your thymeleaf page and re-run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your dependencies. You are mixing Spring Boot version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT with Spring Boot 2.7.0. That isn't going to work for several reasons, the major one being that 3.0.0 is for JakartaEE whilest 2.7.0 is for JavaEE. Different APIs, different implementation and totally incompatible.

This also means you are using a Thymeleaf version for JakartaEE **not** JavaEE. The version you included is for an older version of Thymeleaf and will now get ignored.

Fix your pom. Don't use Spring Boot 3.0.0 yet as that isn't even final stick with 2.7.0.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.historicalReferenceBook</groupId>
<artifactId>historicalReferenceBook</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>historicalReferenceBook</name>
<description>historicalReferenceBook</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-money</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

In short

1. Use version 2.7.0 of Spring Boot, not 3.0.0 (which is still under development)
2. Never mix versions of a framework, regardless of which framework but that is trouble waiting to happen. (Spring Boot in this case 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 2.7.0)
3. Don't try to outsmart the dependency management from Spring Boot, or if you do so do it properly (the Spring Security dialect for thymeleaf)
4. Use the proper dependencies for what you want to use (`spring-boot-starter-validation` instead of `validation-api`)